# Error In VS Code Destination Directory and Says Access Denied

Tags: visual-studio-code, flatfiledestination

I am trying to code my website in **VS Code** that is hosted in my local host **Xammp server** and when I open this file is shows me a popup with error having this path  `C:\User\ideal computer\AppData\Local\Program\Microsoft VS Code\unins000.exe`

When I search the path in my C drive it does not show any path. I don't know what is the problem if anyone know how to solve this problem, I would love to appreciate his/her response.

Here is the screenshot of Error Popup

[image: screenshot that shows destination error]

Thanks To All Stack Overflow Developers Family ☺

Comment: Just because you don't see it doesn't mean it's not there - the `AppData` folder is hidden by default.

Comment: how do i show this folder

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5